# Converting a GeoTIFF image from RGB to gray scale using Rasterio or GDAL in Python

Tags: raster, gdal, rasterio, color

I was using `PIL` to convert some images from RGB to gray scale in Python, but this code does not work well for GeoTIFF files. It seems that `PIL` does not seem to work with with GeoTIFF files in particular.

I was using the code:

```
from PIL import Image

t = Image.open('testfile.tif')
gray_image = image.convert('L')
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to load an image in say `rasterio` and then convert it to a  gray scale array. Now I could manually do this by writing a simple function to matrix multiply the image array, BUT the files are pretty large and so I run into memory issues. So I would likely need to do a windowed read on the file.

If there is a convenience function in `rasterio` or `GDAL` for this, could someone point it out. I searched but could not find anything. Otherwise I can try to work on creating a windowed read.

Comment: I found with https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rasterio+windowed+read&ia=web this "Windowed reading and writing" document https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html as the first hit.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks. Yes, I am aware of the windowed reads functionality. The `PIL` utility seems to handle converting to grayscale without blowing up the memory, so I imagine it already implements a windowed read, though I am not sure. I was just wondering if `rasterio` or `GDAL` provide a similar functionality. I can write windows myself, but was wondering whether I needed to or not.

Comment: I don't think rasterio has a convenience function to do windowed RW transparently, but implementing `block_windows()` should only take an extra a line or two of code

Comment: @mikewatt yep, that is what I was working on. The additional pain point I discovered is that I also have to apply `blocks_windows()` over the output array for the gray scale image, haha. I found that trying to preallocate a (31833, 39197) float64 array did not go very well.

Comment: You can use the same window that the source image's `blocks_windows()` returns when you go to write the output image, no need to pre-create the output or iterate over anything separately